# NPM Run <script> doesn't run any script

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run any script with npm, no matter in what project, I get errors.
For example when I run  `npm run start` I get the following error:

```
nasteas-MacBook-Pro:newapp nastea$ npm run start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/nastea/.npm/_logs/2020-01-02T19_28_32_592Z-debug.log
```

this is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "01-first-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "amocrm-api": "^1.3.1"
  }
}
```

These are the logs:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.14.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:350:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:115:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:239:13)
5 verbose cwd /Users/nastea/Downloads/nodejs-basics-tutorial-master/01-first-app/newapp
6 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
7 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "start"
8 verbose node v12.14.0
9 verbose npm  v6.13.4
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried the following:
1. uninstalling and re-installing node.
2. `npm config get ignore-scripts` returns `false`

What could be the solution? Any help would be much appreciated.

Later edit: node doesn't run any .js file in terminal either.

Edit: `run start` works now.

Comment: Can you try `npm start` (or `npm test`)?

Comment: thank you for you suggestion, I get the same error.

Comment: just to double check, you do have a server.js at the root level?

Comment: push your code to github that doesn't run and let me reproduce it locally. It looks like there is no problem with your package.json

Comment: Yes, the server.js is at the root level. Also, node doesn't run any .js file in terminal either.

Comment: here is the github link, thank you for your help: https://github.com/Nastea/newapp

Comment: Works for me. I can't reproduce your error. Are you sure, that you use just `npm start` (without `run`)?

Comment: I restarted my visual code and it now works, with `npm start`). Or maybe I was doing something wrong. Thank you for your help!